# Installing Ghost EACCES error

Tags: node.js, ghost

I'm trying to install [ghost](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost) but shows this error when building Bookshelf.js:

> Installing dependencies
>   npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/babel-cli/6.18.0/package'

```
sudo  npm install -g  ghost --allow-root
```

Comment: You might look over the recommendations in "[Fixing npm permissions](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)." Also, does an aspect of your setup require you to use `sudo` or have you tried installing `ghost` globally without it?

Comment: i solve this question using unsafe-perm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve using this:

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm ghost --allow-root 
npm config set prefix ~/npm
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/npm/bin"
```